# Is there a way for an aircraft to tell a ground station when the gear is down?

Tags: airline-operations, landing-gear

Is there any way that someone on the ground can be informed if the landing gear is down? It could be an ACARS message sent to the ground center, or a specific light (sequence) from the aircraft that someone can see visually, or something else. If there is nothing today, is there something that could work in future for all aircraft?

Comment: [A decent pair of Binoculars is all you need](https://www.eagleoptics.com/collections/binoculars)

Comment: Are you asking if a) the aircraft can tell someone on the ground when the gear is down, or b) someone on the ground can tell the aircraft when the gear is down?

Comment: Both possibilities, if ACARS is already sending this data to the ground center or any other parameter (already being sent) in ACARS that can indicate that state. If that is not possible then am trying to find other solution where if a specific light or any other unique identification that can be used. May be a specific flashing light or anything else. The aim is to find a way to identify this event from the ground , either via ACARS or visual indication.Thanks

Comment: Based on your comment, I edited your question to make it a little clearer but if I got it wrong please just roll back the edit or edit it again yourself.

Comment: @Ramin What's wrong with radio?

Comment: What purpose would there be for the ground to know whether the gear is down or not?

Comment: Who exactly do you need to tell that the gear is down? Just a random bystander?

Comment: Researching on automating data collection for parameters and scenario defined above .

Comment: What would someone on the ground do with the information, besides possibly inform the pilot?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, ACARS reports the block time and flight time already. That consists of parking brake release and parking brake set (block time), and weight off wheels to weight on wheels (flight time). These are to help airline maintenance keep track of when they need to do inspections, etc. It would certainly be *possible* to program it to report wheels up and down, but currently there's no reason to have it report those times.

I'm not sure if you're talking about having this reported in real time or not, but automatic ACARS reports are not exactly in real time. They can transmit things right away (such as text messages from the crew) as long as they have a network connection. But the automated messages are queued for transmission as a block and some types of messages are prioritized over others.

If you're talking about just collecting this data for later analysis, many aircraft are equipped with a quick access recorder (QAR) which records numerous flight parameters. I'm fairly sure wheels up and down times are usually collected. QARs are intended to give information about the flight that can be collected after a flight lands, either by USB, cellular or removable memory cards/disks/tapes. These are collected periodically, such as when the plane returns to the airline hub. This data is used by airlines as part of their flight data monitoring program which looks for incidents that exceed defined thresholds or trends that are occurring to help identify possible safety risks. So the airlines already have a method to collect gear position data.

Answer (score 1):

It is technologically possible to do, and could be retrofitted to all airplanes of all sizes with retractable gear, although you'd need to also fit the system to fixed gear airplanes as well so people on the ground could rest easy in the knowledge that the gear on those airplanes will always be down. The system could be lights, or a radio based system, satellite based, or other technologies.

This system does not exist because the benefits of the system aren't worth the cost of implementing it. It would cost billions to implement the technology for no improvement in safety or operations.

Comment: Thanks, my research is about probably finding some solution where there is no change to planes or airlines. Just have to figure out a way where some existing ACARS message can be used or some other external system on the ground can detect that event. Just have to track that event. I really hope and best case scenario would be that there is some ACARS message that is already been sent that can detect this event.

Comment: I think you need to get a bit clearer about what your expectations should be. There is no easy or cheap solution to what you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks, My first task would be to find a ACARS message that is already being sent while on Approach and if that message has some indication in it if the gear is down or up.There would be so much information that would be passed on from the Plane to ground. Just wanted to know if any message/parameter sent has that info.